# Is it possible to cool a hot drink by inhaling the steam from the drink?

Tags: evaporation

Say we have a hot cup of coffee that is giving off steam. It is releasing heat into the environment through radiation and conduction. The steam is from certain particles reaching a high enough kinetic energy as to escape the attractive, intermolecular forces that bind them intrinsically. If we physically inhaled steam, thereby increasing the rate of heat loss through steam, would it effectively cool the coffee?

Answer (score 0):

As hot water, at its surface, turns to steam the water loses some energy and its temperature falls. You need to prevent the steam from condensing back, so giving back latent heat to the water. You could either blow the steam away, or you could, indeed, inhale it (though it might not do you much good). Either way you will be preventing the steam from recondensing into the water.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would be gracious enough to give a reason for the downvote, and the original poster of the question might say why she/he withdrew acceptance of the answer.

Comment: Could you read the question and the description to it again and change your answer. Because now it's a little bit not accurate

Comment: And by inhaling you are also bringing in new, cool, unsaturated air over the drink just like blowing on it would. Except, of course, that hot steam in your throat doesn't do you much good...

Comment: @JonCuster Will it benefit the drink? Will he be able to cool down faster this way?